# Add row styling when data populated, remove on mouse hover

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm currently using Bootstrap Vue's b-table to display my data from the database. I have SignalR implemented, where it will automatically update/refresh the table with the new data received from the server.

I would like to add some sort of highlight css styling or [row variant](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#items-record-data)
when new data gets populated into the table, and then remove the styling from the row on mouseover/hover. Currently, I can receive events in the console when a row gets hovered.

How am I able to achieve this functionality using Vue.js?

b-table

```html
<b-table
...
    :items="items"
    :fields="fields"
    @row-hovered="myRowHoverHandler"
...
> ... </b-table>
```

script tag

```js
props: {
...
    items: Array,
...
}

methods: {
    myRowHoverHandler(record, index) {
      console.log(this.items[index].id);
    },
...
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an update mechanism, so that new rows are marked as such and this to go away after being hovered once?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Yes, I am looking to implement that. Hiws's current solution seems to be the closest to what I am looking to implement, but I have not tested it on my side yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the item gets updated, you can simply set the `_rowVariant` on the item that got updated, and then on hover remove it from the item again as shown in the codepen below.

Remember to use `$set` and `$delete` to keep Vue's Reactivity happy

https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/WqKqdG